# R Looking for fast solution to identify substrings in large vector of strings

Tags: r, string, substring

I have a vector with substrings and a larger vector with texts (sometimes somehwat longer strings). I would like to identify all substrings in the text vector. I have a simple for loop solution, but this takes too long, since I have large data. In my code the first for loop needs about 6 secs whereas the second one needs 1.3 secs.
The texts and substrings are silly examples. Here, it is all the same, but in my example the strings differ for each row in the dataframes. I basically want to store for each substring the ID of the corresponding text.

Edit: To clarify the question from below, I want to match the substring with the beginning of each text. That's why I restrict the text to the substring with length of the df.substring$subtringx. The substring can however vary in size.

```
df <- data.frame(text = (rep("abcasdashgsdgsdfaasdaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasasdaasdasdasdasdasdasdasddasssssssasdasdasdws",100000)),
                 id = seq(1:100000))
df$text <- as.character(df$text)
df <- rbind(df,data.frame(text = "gsdfasdasdasdasfoisnhfoiajdfoaisjdoiajndoiasjdoasijdaoisjdoaisjda",id=100001))

df.substring <- data.frame(substringx = rep("gsdf",200))
df.substring$substringx <- as.character(df.substring$substringx)
df.substring$id <- ""


before <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(df.substring)){
  df.substring$id[i] <- paste(as.character(df$id[stringsim(df.substring$substringx[i],substr(df$text,1,nchar(df.substring$substringx[i]))) > 0.85]),collapse=";")
}
after <- Sys.time()
after - before


before <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(df.substring)){
  df.substring$id[i] <- paste(as.character(df$id[df.substring$substringx[i] == substr(df$text,1,nchar(df.substring$substringx[i]))]),collapse=";")
}
after <- Sys.time()
after - before
```

I would be awesome to have solutions (for each for loop) which only take 1/10 of the time.

Comment: How often will this code run?

Comment: i have to run this around 50k times. The vectors with texts and substrings are actually larger in my real data. Currently, my code is running for several days. That's why I want to make this part more efficient.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to find all the text lines where each substring occurs at the beginning or at any place? From your code it seems like the former but it's not obvious from the question.

Comment: i hope i made it clearer. please see above. (i'm only interested in the beginning of the text).

Answer (score 0):

If you have many substrings with the same length, you can make the part `substr(df$text,1,nchar(df.substring$substringx[i]))` once for all of them and using the substring form before what can improve speed.

```
before <- Sys.time()
tt  <- df$text
for(n in sort(unique(nchar(df.substring$substringx)), decreasing=TRUE)) {
    tt  <- substr(tt,1,n)
    for(i in which(n == nchar(df.substring$substringx))) {
        df.substring$id[i] <- paste(as.character(
df$id[df.substring$substringx[i] == tt]),collapse=";")
    }
}
Sys.time() - before
#Time difference of 0.1532843 secs

#Compared to the faster solution of the question
before <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(df.substring)){
  df.substring$id[i] <- paste(as.character(df$id[df.substring$substringx[i] == substr(df$text,1,nchar(df.substring$substringx[i]))]),collapse=";")
}
Sys.time() - before
#Time difference of 1.045545 secs
```

Comment: okay, i see. unfortunately, these substrings vary in length quite substantially. and, even for this silly data it is not that much faster when using "stringsim" (5.4 vs. 6.3 secs)

Comment: Oh, that's bad, that the length vary. For the sample data the time could be reduced to less than 15% compared to your faster solution on my PC.